# How to concatenate data using a specific index and update a second table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a way to select the Data from the table A, concatenate everything that **has the same index**, and update a table B putting the result of the concatenation with index 1, in the Index 1 row of the Table B.

```
Table A
+-----------+------+-------+
| Type      | Name | Index |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Cake      | A    | 1     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Cookies   | B    | 1     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Ice Cream | C    | 1     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Patatoes  | D    | 1     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Cake      | E    | 2     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Cookies   | F    | 2     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Ice Cream | G    | 2     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Patatoes  | H    | 2     |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

The final table should be:

```
Table B
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| Index | Line                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| 1     | Cake A ; Cookies B; Ice Cream C, Patatoes D |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| 2     | Cake E ; Cookies F; Ice Cream G, Patatoes H |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Oracle? If 11g or higher, look up the `listagg` function in the documentation. There are lots of examples on this site too. If you get stuck then show us what you tried and what was wrong with it. (If you're still on an earlier version, there are some ideas [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to put comma instead of semicolons in your expected output, you can use `listagg`:

```
select
    "Index",
    listagg(Type ||' '||Name, ', ') within group (order by Name) Line
from table_a 
group by "Index";
```

To make an update on table_b, you can use `merge`:

```
merge into table_b b
using (
    select
        "Index",
        listagg(Type ||' '||Name, ', ') within group (order by Name) Line
    from table_a 
    group by "Index"
) a on (
    b."Index" = a."Index" 
)
when matched then update
set b.Line = a.Line;
```

Comment: The select works just fine. But how to I make the update after?  Cause this select gives me as much lines as indexes that I have. Do i need to make a cycle?

Comment: this works perfectly. How are you guys so good with this? where can i practise and exercise to be this good? Can you indicate me?

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation from above approach. Here i have used WM_CONCAT function to concat the values based on Index.
Note : WM_CONCAT is oracle Undocumented Function so may may not work if object not present in database.
Hope this helps too.

```
select idx,
  wmsys.wm_concat(Typ) line -- This is Oracle undocumented function so may not work if this object not present in database
FROM
  (SELECT 'Cake' typ,'A' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cookies' typ,'B' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ice Cream' typ,'C' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cake' typ,'D' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cake' typ,'E' name,2 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cookies' typ,'F' name,2 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ice Cream' typ,'G' name,2 idx FROM dual
  )
GROUP BY idx;


MERGE INTO TABLEB USING
(SELECT idx,
  wmsys.wm_concat(Typ) line
FROM
  (SELECT 'Cake' typ,'A' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cookies' typ,'B' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ice Cream' typ,'C' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cake' typ,'D' name,1 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cake' typ,'E' name,2 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cookies' typ,'F' name,2 idx FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ice Cream' typ,'G' name,2 idx FROM dual
  )
GROUP BY idx
)a ON (a.idx = tableb.idx)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET tableb.line = a.line;
```